# Result (Aborted) when navigating to web portal

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, firefox

I administer a webapp (HP Service Manager). After upgrading browsers (IE, FF) we are not able to access the web front end.

Using the "Dev Tools" in IE, I see the "result" of the request was "(Aborted)." I was expecting to see a 400 or 500 error, so I'm not sure what that means.

[image: error message]

What does this mean? and how do I troubleshoot it?

Running IE 11, HPSM 9.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update HP Service Manager to support new surfer, else don't update your surfer.

In 9.34, IE 11 *should* be supported:

> Note: If you use Internet Explorer, we recommend that you use Internet
>   Explorer 10 or a higher version for better experience and performance.
>   Internet Explorer 8 has some known limitations, for example:
>   From http://saas.y-im.de/help/sm934/Content/whatsnew/concepts/whats_new_in_hp_service_manager_934.htm

At this point the best thing you could do is to log into your product portal to see if any hotfix is done for better compatibility with IE11.

As I seen some like;

> ID:QCCR1E124497 Status was updated to: Investigation  Title: SM 9.34
>   Web Client Memory leak with IE11

Comment: Is there more documentation on HP's site? I'd love to get a list of their supported browsers. I am unable to find that.

Comment: @Jeff Let us know your version please then